# Django NoReverseMatch with keyword argument not found

Tags: django, python-3.x, foreign-keys

thank you for your help. long store short, here is my git repo. https://github.com/nelsonyan/track 
I have the following error message while clicking on the href in line 22 of `employee_list.html`. It is supposed to take me to the `employee_detail.html` to update but gave me the following error about `track_delete` URL tag... The two apps (report, employee) have foreign key associated, but I don't see why the update function of employee app is related to the delete function of report app. Can any Django expert help me out?

> GET Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/employee/update/7/ Django
>   Version:  2.0.5 Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch Exception Value:
>
> Reverse for 'track_delete' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not
>   found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['report\/delete\/(?P[0-9]+)\/$']
>
> Exception Location:
>     C:\Users\Nelson\Anaconda3\envs\mydjangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py
>   in _reverse_with_prefix, line 632 Python Executable:
>     C:\Users\Nelson\Anaconda3\envs\mydjangoenv\python.exe Python Version:
>     3.6.6

In detail, I am trying to create a site to track art project and display company staff info. The report app works well. It can create/display/update/delete report record. I am simply duplicating the update function to the employee app but have the above problem. It is probably the models of report app has two foreign keys of the same class from employee app's models (`employeelist`). that is why the two apps are associated but I just don't know how to fix this issue while maintaining this relationship.I am new to Django, any advice is welcome.
Thank you

employee_list

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% block office_block%}
{% if employee_list %}
    <title>Employee List</title>
    <table class = 'table table-striped table-hover' id = 'my_table'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><button type="button" class = ' btn btn-info' onclick = 'sortTable(0)'>Name</button></th>
          <th><button type="button" class = ' btn btn-info' onclick = 'sortTable(1)'>Phone Ex</button></th>
          <th><button type="button" class = ' btn btn-info' onclick = 'sortTable(2)'>Email</button></th>
          <th><button type="button" class = ' btn btn-info' onclick = 'sortTable(3)'>Department</button></th>
          <th><button type="button" class = ' btn btn-info' onclick = 'sortTable(4)'>Remote Access</button></th>
          <th>Cell Phone</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for EL in employee_list %}
          <tr>
            <td><a href="{% url 'employee:employee_update' pk=EL.id %}">{{EL.first_name}} {{EL.last_name}}</a></td>
            <td>{{EL.phone_ex}}</td>
            <td>{{EL.email}}</td>
            <td>{{EL.department}}</td>
            <td>{{EL.remote_access}}</td>
            <td>{{EL.cell}}</td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  <!-- </div> -->
{% else %}
  <p class = 'bg-primary'>Employee List not found</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'employee'
urlpatterns = [
path('output/', views.EmployeeOutput.as_view(), name = 'employee_list'),
path('input/', views.EmployeeInput.as_view(), name = 'employee_input'),
path('update/<int:pk>/', views.EmployeeUpdate.as_view(), name = 'employee_update'),
]
```

views.py employee APP

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import models
from employee.forms import EmployeeInputForms
from django.views.generic import (ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView,)

class EmployeeOutput(ListView):
model = models.EmployeeList
context_object_name = 'employee_list'
template_name = 'employee_list.html'


class EmployeeInput(CreateView):
model = models.EmployeeList
template_name = 'employee_input.html'

form_class = EmployeeInputForms

class EmployeeUpdate(UpdateView):
model = models.EmployeeList
form_class = EmployeeInputForms
context_object_name = 'employee_detail'
template_name = 'employee_detail.html'
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}       {# import bootstrap4/bootstrap3 #}
{% bootstrap_css %}         {# Embed Bootstrap CSS #}
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}  {# Embed Bootstrap JS+jQuery #}

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/my_css.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<div class = 'body_style'>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light sticky-top" style =     'background-color: #7DBAF2;'>
    <a class="navbar-brand">Marklyn</a>
    <button type="button" class = 'navbar-toggler' data-toggle = 'collapse' data-target = '#navbarSupportedContent' aria-controls = 'navbarSupportedContent' aria-expanded = 'false'
    aria-label  = 'Toggle navigation'> <span class = 'navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id = 'navbarSupportedContent'>
      <ul class = 'navbar-nav mr-auto'>
        <li class = 'nav-item active'><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home:home_page' %}"> <button type="button" class = 'btn btn-secondary'>Home</button><span class = 'sr-only'>(current)</span> </a></li>
        <li class = 'nav-item active'><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'admin:index' %}"> <button type="button" class = 'btn btn-secondary'>Admin</button><span class = 'sr-only'>(current)</span> </a></li>
        <li class = 'nav-item active'><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'report:track_report' %}"> <button type="button" class = 'btn btn-secondary'>Report</button><span class = 'sr-only'>(current)</span> </a></li>
        <li class = 'nav-item active'><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'report:track_input' %}"> <button type="button" class = 'btn btn-secondary'>Enter Request</button><span class = 'sr-only'>(current)</span> </a></li>
        <li class = 'nav-item active'><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'report:track_data_export' %}"> <button type="button" class = 'btn btn-secondary'>Export data</button><span class = 'sr-only'>(current)</span> </a></li>
        <li class = 'nav-item active'><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'employee:employee_list' %}"> <button type="button" class = 'btn btn-secondary'>Staff</button><span class = 'sr-only'>(current)</span> </a></li>
        <li class = 'nav-item active'><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'employee:employee_input' %}"> <button type="button" class = 'btn btn-secondary'>Create Staff</button><span class = 'sr-only'>(current)</span> </a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <ul class = 'navbar-nav ml-auto'>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" >
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'authentication:register' %}"> <button type="button" class = 'btn btn-primary'>Register</button></a></li>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <li> <a class = 'navbar-link' href="{% url 'authentication:user_logout' %}"><button type="button" class = 'btn btn-success'>Logout</button></a></li>
        {% else %}
          <li> <a class = 'navbar-link' href="{% url 'authentication:user_login' %}"><button type="button" class = 'btn btn-warning'>Login</button></a></li>
        {% endif %}
      </form>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="bar_on_top">
    {% block office_block %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
</div>

<script src = "{% static '/js/sort.js' %}"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

employee_detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block office_block%}
<title>Request Detail</title>
<h1 class = 'my_header'>
  Update Current Request
</h1> <br>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <table class = 'table table-hover'>
          {{forml}}
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class = 'btn btn-info' value="Update">
      <!-- <a href="{% url 'report:track_delete' pk=form_delete.pk %}"><button type="button" class = 'btn btn-danger'>Delete</button></a> -->
      <!-- <a href="{% url 'report:track_report'%}"><button type="button" class = 'btn btn-warning'>Cancel</button></a> -->
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What does the `line 22 of employee_list.html` say? Obviously you have a link (a `{% url %}` tag) there that tries to pass a `pk` argument while your `delete` url doesn't expect that.

Comment: Just noticed that you posted `employee_list.html` while the error is in your `employee_detail.html`: `GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/employee/update/7`. Post `employee_detail.html` please.

Comment: ok, employee_detail.html is updated. I tried to use the actual context objects name: employee_detail instead of 'form'. It does not seem to make a difference...

Comment: ok. O see where the problem is. Django parse the comment section of employee_detail.html, even if it is commented out... I remove those two comment line, which points to report, It all works out. Thank you all for your help and support!!

Comment: Yes it is only hidden from the browser. If you really comment it out use `{% comment %}` template tags.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was found to be a bug in versions below the 2.1.5 versions of Django and that bug is resolved in Django 2.1.5. So install Django 2.1.5 you'll not get any errors.